# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define in Android

Tags: android, android-annotations

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/googlecode/androidannotations/annotations/AfterInject;

Here, I am using the androidannotations-2.7.1 jar.
suggest me some good suggestions

Comment: My problem was resolved. This error can happen if you have two jars that contains the same class names, e.g. I had two library: android-api-X.X.X.jar, and android-api-X.X.X.jar,  I removed android annotations-X.X.X.jar and it works.

Comment: would you please guide me on how to remove the similar .jar files